# core data in tab bar view

Tags: ios5, core-data, ios4

I am trying to do an App with tab bar controller, one of this tab has to be a tableView with core data functions. The first question is do I need to use a navigation controller before the TableView or I can go from tab bar direct to the TableView?

At the moment my project is from tab Bar to tableView but I am stack on this error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Event' " that looks a pretty much common error.

When I run the app is working but when I am trying to go on the tab with table view is crashing. I am new in programming is quite easy to be stack for me.

Any idea/help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to use a navigation controller to use a table view controller.

That core data error means the entity "Event" is not in your model.  Either you are not loading the right model, or you are using the wrong entity name.

Comment: OK.. now that error is fix. I continued with app the new error is " Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'"

Comment: Exactly what it says.  You have no model.  I assume you are using the core data template generated by Xcode...  set a breakpoint at the method to access the persistentStoreCoordinator, and track it through its creation.  You will readily see what failed to cause the model to not load.

Comment: No.. I started the app from a tabbed application and i am trying to fit inside a open source project that i found on internet. But the project is starting from empty project and i got some problem how to work out the App delegate with a tabbed project.

Comment: Somewhere, there is a method that is creating the persistent store coordinator.  That's where you need to set a breakpoint to see why its failing.

Comment: Now is not crashing anymore but where i tried to create a a bar with 2 button to add and edit nothing is coming out. Probably my skills are too weak to try to do a project like this now. I am getting a bit frustrated is almost 2 week that turning around this project read a lot tutorial a watching hundred video without getting anything. Thanks for now..

Comment: I suggest starting with a brand new project that has a single view controller and uses core data.  Work with that to get comfortable with how to interact with core data and table views.  I have zero affiliation with Ray Wenderlich (wouldn't know him if he showed up for dinner), but he has lots of really good beginner level tutorials available on his website.

Comment: Hi Jody.. In these days I studied the tutorial that you said to me. Now is a bit more clear, but I m still stack with the same problem. now I've got some more clue. This is the error >> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name like before. I know the error is coming fro this line    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DiveLocation" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];    I check the name is correct. Looks that I am not able to get in entity. Thanks again for yr help.